# Default section header for UITableViewPlain?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, header

Similar question: [How to mimic UITableView's UITableViewStylePlain section header style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664687/how-to-mimic-uitableviews-uitableviewstyleplain-section-header-style)
No complete answers. BarrettJ's is close, but not quite there.

An image would seem to be the simplest, most efficient way to do it, but I can't get the right dimensions/position, and even when I'm close, it still looks different in the first and second headers. (Something different about the top of the table view?)

Text is not an issue. I just need something to fill the space and look exactly the same as the default header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.sectionHeaderHeight)];
    sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0];
    sectionHeaderView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    sectionHeaderView.tag = section;

    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -1, tableView.bounds.size.width, 23)];
    backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 2, tableView.bounds.size.width-10, 18)];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    headerLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    [sectionHeaderView addSubview:backgroundImageView];
    [sectionHeaderView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Fixed it. Anyone can use/modify this.

[image: header.png]